# export dates from spreadsheet to text files google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an spreadsheet with information like this:

```
Columnn 1 Column 2
Event 1   00:00:00
Event 2   00:03:25
.
.
```

If I use this script:

```
function export() {
  var folderName = "the folder";    
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();      
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var text = values.map(function (a) {return a.join(' ');}).join('\n');
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(name+'.txt', text);
  folder.addFile(file);      
}
```

I got a file like this:

```
Event 1 Sat Dec 30 1899 01:42:46 GMT-0300 (CLST)
Event 2 Sat Dec 30 1899 01:46:11 GMT-0300 (CLST)
.
.
```

But I would like it to be like:

```
Event 1 00:00:00
Event 2 00:03:25
.
.
```

What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: I'm assuming your numbers are time durations.  Try this        Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(value,Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss")); where value is the cell value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When getting date/time data, Google scripts converts it into a date time javascript object.
- Use [`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues()) instead:

  ```
   var values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  ```